# Can list comprehension assist in shortening this code?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am a complete beginner to coding, having started Python about 3 weeks ago. I was invited to an online challenge (using python 2.7) which I am using as an opportunity for practice. The current challenge asks for a function that takes a list of integers and returns the maximum product of some non-empty subset of those numbers.

The following code works--ie. it passes the test posed by the challenge--but I have the feeling it is overlong and clunky. I'm not in a position to assess whether it is fast or slow but would assume the latter. Does anyone have a suggestion for a good resource that would help me understand how to improve this type of code for future cases? (eg. something that explains list comprehension well, perhaps?)

```
def solution(xs) :
    neglist = list()
    poslist = list()
    endlist = list()
    for number in xs :
        if number == 0 : continue
        if number < 0 : neglist.append(number)
        if number > 0 : poslist.append(number)
    neglist.sort()
    poslist.sort()
    if len(neglist) > 1 and len(neglist)% 2 != 0 :
        neglist = neglist[:-1]
    for number in neglist :
        endlist.append(number)
    for number in poslist :
        endlist.append(number)
    output = 1
    for number in endlist :
        output *= number
    if output < 0 and 0 in xs: output = 0
    return str(output)
```

Comment: See [codereview.se] for code reviewing and improvements. SO is for specific coding questions, not general code overview

Comment: why when i call solution([1, 2, 3]) it returns 6 ? you did not consider about subsets with length of 1 ?

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks for the pointer, apologies for this being in the wrong place

Comment: @DRPK it's highly possible I made a mistake but my understanding of the question is that the correct solution to [1,2,3] is indeed 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last 5 lines are correct (from `output = 1` to the end) then you can replace with list comprehension quite compactly.

```
def split_pos_neg(original):
    original.sort()
    pos = [x for x in original if x > 0]
    neg = [x for x in original if x < 0]
    print (pos)
    print (neg)
    return

orig = [3, 15, -2, -98, 0, 1]
split_pos_neg(orig) # prints [1, 3, 15] and [-98, -2]
```

The code `pos = [x for x in original if x > 0]` creates a new list, called pos, for each element of the original list that is positive.

Comment: fantastic, thank you!